# C#: Generating a table from a .CSV that counts name (string) occurences in another table

Tags: c#, csv

I am importing a data table from a `.csv` file with headers, and this is no problem.
So let us call the file `dt.csv`.

One column header is named `companyName`.

But I need to create a new table where I, first of all, list all the companies from the first data table and count how many times each `companyName` does appear in the first table.

The first table can have anything from 500 to 5000 lines, but the number of different companies appearing will only be 15-50. The challenge is that I do not know the company names to expect in advance, so I cannot make a positive list to count against. I need the list to count against to be generated based on the content of column `companyName` (so that I do not get duplicates of the same name).

Comment: I improved some formatting/spelling and the title.

Answer (score 0):

This code is C# but is largely pseudocode as I'm not certain of your approach to reading / writing the CSV file:

```
var seenCompanies = new List<string>();
foreach(var line in csvFile)
{
    seenCompanies.Add(line.GetColumn("companyName"));
}

var companiesAndCounts = 
    seenCompanies
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
    .ToList();

foreach(var group in companiesAndCounts)
{
    outputFile.Write(group.Name + "," + group.Count);
}
```

This is pretty standard conceptually, all you're really doing is just counting the occurrences of each distinct company name and then writing that out.

You can adapt this to better suit your needs, but it should be enough to show how it can be approached.

Comment: Thanks this looks like a nice structured sequence which I will test run during the weekend - but now I add a complication to it, as I have another count with 2 conditions, where one of then is the seen Companies and another one created with the same methodology which I call seenCreatedDate, that is generated from a column named createdDate which is in a date format YYYY-MM. Now I like a new table where I on the horizontal axis has seenCompanies and on the vertical axis has the seenCreated dates and then in this matrix count appearences that match both criterias??

Comment: Hi @MikaelD you can just track additional data as necessary as you go.

Comment: I could make a column seenCompanies+" "+seenCreatedDate and count the appearences the same way, but that would be a very long list and not nice to review

Comment: Hi Clint - what libraries are you using to support the code? I am a newborn rookie in this, so I need to know how to utilize what is already build. I use these just now                                                                           using System;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO;

Comment: Hi @MikaelD my answer doesn't assume any framework in particular, it's more a guide for **how to approach** the problem, rather than how to solve it with your particular choice of technologies. You can always just read the CSV file manually and split the columns out with `String.Split`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Clint

Answer (score 0):

You can also use System.Generics.Dictionary

```
//I used this list to test, you should replace "companies" with a list from you csv file
List<string> companies = new List<string>(){"c1","c2","c1","c4","c3","c3","c3","c2"};

Dictionary<string,int> numberOfAppearance = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(string company in companies)
{
    if(numberOfAppearance.ContainsKey(company))
        numberOfAppearance[company]++;
    else
        numberOfAppearance.Add(company, 1);
}
//Now numberOfAppearance["companyName"] holds the number of appearances of the company named companyName in the list
```

I created a List to hold all the company names as I don't know how you store them from your csv file, but It should be easy to adapt.